# Cypress Assertion TimeOut issue in browser headless mode

Tags: cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

I'm working on creating cypress code for end-to-end testing of my angular-ui application. The issue is that cypress code is throwing the following AssertionError related to Timeout very often.

```
  AssertionError: Timed out retrying after 60000ms: Expected to find element: `#dialogSubmit`, but never found it.
  at Context.eval (webpack://myapp-tests/./cypress/e2e/step_definitions/grammar_requests.ts:883:54)
  at Registry.runStepDefininition (webpack://myapp-tests/./node_modules/@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/lib/registry.js:119:0)
  at Object.fn (webpack://myapp-tests/./node_modules/@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/lib/create-tests.js:305:0)
  at runStepWithLogGroup (webpack://myapp-tests/./node_modules/@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/lib/cypress.js:11:0)
  at Context.eval (webpack://myapp-tests/./node_modules/@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/lib/create-tests.js:302:0)
```

The error is not consistent i.e., sometimes it occurs and sometime it doesn't. I tried increasing the timeout value to very large number (10mins) for testing but it didn't work. I don't see any issue with that particular element loading When I manually test that feature i.e., #dialogSubmit element loads within 3secs.

Here is the test feature definition -

```
Then(`The user should see the CSS elements on the UI for the client {string} and task {string}`, (clientId:string, task:string) => {
let data = require('../../fixtures/clientsdata.json');
let primaryColor = data[clientId].primaryColor;
let ButtonFonts = data[clientId].ButtonFonts;
let Fonts = data[clientId].Fonts;
cy.document().its('head').find('link[rel=icon]', {timeout:60000}).should('have.attr', 'href').should('eq', data[clientId].favicon);
cy.title().should('include', data[clientId].titleText);
cy.wait(2500);
cy.get('#taskTitle').should('have.css', 'font-family', (ButtonFonts || 'Times New Roman') );
cy.get('#transaction-welcome-message').should('have.css', 'font-family', Fonts);
if(clientId.toString().indexOf('client1') == -1){
    cy.get('#header-toolbar').should('have.css', 'background-image', data[clientId]["background-image"]).should('have.css', 'background-position', data[clientId]["background-position"]);
}
if(task === 'TASK1'){
    cy.get('.mat-mdc-raised-button:not(:disabled)').should('have.css', 'background-color', primaryColor).should("have.css", 'font-family', ButtonFonts);
    cy.get('.mat-mdc-raised-button:not(:disabled)').click();
    cy.get('#zoomIn').should('have.css', 'background-color', primaryColor);
    cy.get('#zoomOut').should('have.css', 'background-color', primaryColor);
    cy.get('#download').should('have.css', 'background-color', primaryColor);
    cy.get('#back').should('have.css', 'background-color', primaryColor).should('have.css', 'font-family', ButtonFonts);
    if(clientId.toString().indexOf('client1') == -1){
        cy.get('#header-toolbar').should('have.css', 'background-image', data[clientId]["background-image"]).should('have.css', 'background-position', data[clientId]["background-position"]);
    }
}
else if(task === 'TASK2'){
    cy.get('#taskDescription').should('have.css', 'font-family', Fonts);
    cy.get('#attachFileButton').should('have.css', 'background-color', primaryColor).should('have.css', 'font-family', ButtonFonts);
    cy.get('#uploadButton').should('have.css', 'background-color', primaryColor).should('have.css', 'font-family', ButtonFonts);
}
else{
    cy.get('.mat-mdc-raised-button:not(:disabled)').should('have.css', 'background-color', primaryColor).should("have.css", 'font-family', ButtonFonts);
    cy.get('.mat-mdc-raised-button:not(:disabled)').click();
    cy.get('#mat-mdc-dialog-0 > div > div > app-esign-disclosure > div.buttons > button.right.mdc-button.mdc-button--raised.mat-mdc-raised-button.mat-primary.mat-mdc-button-base').should('have.css', 'background-color', primaryColor).should('have.css', 'font-family', ButtonFonts).click();
    cy.wait(2000);
    cy.get('#zoomIn').should('have.css', 'background-color', primaryColor);
    cy.get('#zoomOut').should('have.css', 'background-color', primaryColor);
    cy.get('#download').should('have.css', 'background-color', primaryColor);
    cy.get('#nextVariable').should('have.css', 'background-color', primaryColor).should('have.css', 'font-family', ButtonFonts).wait(2000).click();
    cy.get('#nextVariable').click().click();
    cy.get('#previousVariable').should('have.css', 'background-color', primaryColor).should('have.css', 'font-family', ButtonFonts);
    cy.get('#\\38 0672996-fa2c-4777-af24-1fc4cee2bf32 > .incompleteVariable').click();
    cy.get('#eb919b5a-1dda-4716-b5ea-7899fe7f807c > .incompleteVariable').click()
    cy.wait(3000);
    if(clientId.toString().indexOf('client1') == -1){
        cy.get('#dialogSubmit', {timeout:60000}).should('have.css', 'background-color', primaryColor).should('have.css', 'font-family', ButtonFonts);
        cy.get('#header-toolbar').should('have.css', 'background-image', data[clientId]["background-image"]).should('have.css', 'background-position', data[clientId]["background-position"]);
        cy.get('#mat-mdc-dialog-1 > div > div > app-task-can-be-submitted-dialog > div.mat-mdc-dialog-actions.mdc-dialog__actions.mat-mdc-dialog-actions-align-end > button.mdc-button.mat-mdc-button.mat-unthemed.mat-mdc-button-base').click();
        cy.get('#submitTask').should('have.css', 'background-color', primaryColor).should('have.css', 'font-family', ButtonFonts);
        cy.get('#submitTask').click();
        cy.get('#taskDone').should('have.css', 'background-color', primaryColor).should('have.css', 'font-family', ButtonFonts);
        cy.get('#header-toolbar').should('have.css', 'background-image', data[clientId]["background-image"]).should('have.css', 'background-position', data[clientId]["background-position"]);
        cy.get('#taskDone').click();
    }
    cy.contains('VIEW', {timeout:60000}).should('have.css', 'background-color', primaryColor);
}});
```

I even added following configuration to cypress like defaultCommandTimeout, chromeWebSecurity but no luck.

```
export default defineConfig({
   chromeWebSecurity: false,
   defaultCommandTimeout: 60000,
   e2e: {
      specPattern: "cypress/e2e/features/*.feature",
      supportFile: false,
      setupNodeEvents
   }});
```

I'm sure something is blocking when I run the automated test in chrome headless mode which I'm not able to find.

Can someone please help if there is known is in cypress of any reason why my test case fails intermittently.?

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot of the failure while running cypress UI? (`npx cypress open`)
Ensure you have the element focused in the browser console while you take the screenshot